# How do I open a tag in an existing gvim instance?

Tags: gvim, tags, clientserver

On windows I use gvim, and like to keep just one gvim instance running. Most of the time I open files like this:
`gvim -p --remote-tab-silent FILES`.
However, sometimes I want to open a tag in that same remote gvim server in a new tab. If I do
`gvim -t MYFUNCTION --remote-tab-silent` it tells me it wants a file name after the last argument.
If I do `gvim --remote-tab-silent -t MYFUNCTION` it opens a new tab with a split window with two files, one named literally `-t` and the other named `MYFUNCTION`.
I've also tried using `--` to end the arguments list, but then I end up editing a file named `--`.

How can I open a tag in my existing gvim instance?

Comment: Can you not just switch to the gvim instance and run `:tag` whatever? Why do you need this on the command line

Comment: Have you tried `vim --remote-expr "execute('tag MYFUNCTION')"`? Or `vim --remote-send ":tag MYFUNCTION<cr>"`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble sometimes I have a long function name which I can paste into the command line, but can't paste into the gvim command bar (or whatever the : bar is called)

Comment: Can you use the `*` register on windows gvim? If so: `:tag <C-r>*`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked an example  which Ralf mentioned in the comments to get this:
`gvim --server=$SERVER --remote-send ":execute('tab tag $tag')<CR>"`
Remote send sends the following commands to the gvim server. `<CR>` is the return character.